# Getting AMEDIA_ERROR_BASE what is a problem here?

Tags: android, c++, native, android-mediacodec

```
int32_t NDK_extractor::decode(const unsigned char *pData, long dataSize)
{
    LOGD("Using NDK decoder");
    FILE *fp = nullptr;
    media_status_t err;

    AMediaExtractor *ex = AMediaExtractor_new();

    fp = fmemopen((void *) pData, dataSize, "rb");

    if (fp)
    {
        err = AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd(ex, fileno(fp), 0 /*offset*/, dataSize);
    }
    else
    {
        LOGE("Failed open file");
        return 0;
    }

    if (err != AMEDIA_OK)
    {
        LOGE("SOUND :: Error setting ex data source, err %d", err);  <----- THIS LINE
        return 0;
    }
...
}
```

I try to use `setDataSource` method from `AMediaExtractor` and getting such an error `AMEDIA_ERROR_BASE`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I have found out that problem is that `AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd` wants to get second param as file descriptor, in order to get a file descriptor from FILE you can use `fileno()` method but issue here is that `fileno()` returns -1 if you try to pass pointer on FILE that was opened with `fmemopen()` method. So, in order to make it work I found kind of workaround, so I just get my `data[]` write it in a temporary file then I can get right file descriptor and path it to `AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd` method.